# about paired or unpaired t.test or wilcox.test in R

Tags: r, t-test, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

Please advise on the use of PAIRED or UNPAIRED T.TEST or WILCOXON TEST (`wilcox.test`) in R:

Let's say we have 2 samples:

-- CONTROL : where we measure the expression of 100 genes G1 ... G100 in one million cells C1 ... C1mil

-- TREATMENT : where we measure the expression of 100 genes G1 ... G100 in one million cells D1 ... D1mil

When we compare the expression of these 100 genes G1 ...G100, in CONTROL vs TREATMENT, we should use UNPAIRED TESTS, correct?

(As the cells in CONTROL C1..C1mil are different than the cells in TREATMENT D1..D1mil?)

Comment: For a single cell and a single gene, how is the expression measured?

Comment: If you are comparing expression of the same 100 genes with and without treatment, then you have 100 pairs of values. //  Continuing Demetri's question, are 'expressions' measured in such a way that the _difference_ with and without treatment is a meaningful quantity? Are differences nearly normally distributed? // I'm not following the logic of the Answer by @Wasserman.

Comment: thank you, we can measure the expression of every gene in the genome by RNA-seq, in such a way that we have a data-frame : GENE_1 (expression beforeT, expression afterT) ... GENE_30000 (expression beforeT, expression afterT) ; And, the log2 of expression_beforeT, or log2 of expression_afterT, for all the genes, are normally distributed ..

Comment: I don't know much about gene ecpression so I could understand the set up wrong.  I assume e.g. for a gene G1 Bogdan calculates average expression value for this gene over the milion cells in the treatment group and compares with an analogous average in the control group. The same procedure follows for every gene so there would be 100 such comparisons.  If such comparisons are performed with 95% confidence level even if in fact there is not any difference between the groups for any of the genes we can expect to find 5 significant difference since our test are correct only 95% of times.

Comment: This is exactly multiple comparison problem.

Comment: thank you, yes, I'd say that it is an accurate description of the problem ...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, unpaired tests. You would use paired test if you measured the same cells before the treatment and after treatment.

If I uderstood you correctly you are testing 100 parameters simultainously. In such a case you should also address multiple testing problem:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_comparisons_problem

Comment: thank you gentlemen. For those 100 genes (or for even more genes,  ~30 000 genes that our genome has), their expression is measured by different techniques (RNA-seq, POL2-seq, GRO-seq). For example,  a description of RNA-seq is on wikipedia : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RNA-Seq